# Python dataframe to nested json file

Tags: python, json

I have a python dataframe as below.
python dataframe:-

```
Emp_No  Name    Project Task
1   ABC P1  T1
1   ABC P2  T2
2   DEF P3  T3
3   IJH Null    Null
```

I need to convert it to json file and save it to disk as below

Json File

```
 {
   "Records"[
      {
         "Emp_No":"1",
         "Project_Details":[
            {
               "Project":"P1",
               "Task":"T1"
            },
            {
               "Project":"P2",
               "Task":"T2"
            }
         ],
         "Name":"ÄBC"
      },
      {
         "Emp_No":"2",
         "Project_Details":[
            {
               "Project":"P2",
               "Task":"T3"
            }
         ],
         "Name":"DEF"
      },
      {
         "Emp_No":"3",
         "Project_Details":[
            
         ],
         "Name":"IJH"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre] of your code (what have you tried) and explain what particular problem you cannot solve.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this post is not a doubt per se, but a cheecky atempt to avoid formatting the data, hahaha. But, since i'm trying to get used to the dataframe structure and the different ways of handling it, here you go!

```
import pandas as pd

asutosh_data = {'Emp_No':["1","1","2","3"], 'Name':["ABC","ABC","DEF","IJH"], 'Project':["P1","P2","P3","Null"], 'Task':["T1","T2","T3","Null"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=asutosh_data)

records = [] 

dif_emp_no = df['Emp_No'].unique()

for emp_no in dif_emp_no :

    emp_data = df.loc[df['Emp_No'] == emp_no]
    emp_project_details = []
    for index,data in emp_data.iterrows():
        if data["Project"]!="Null":
            emp_project_details.append({"Project":data["Project"],"Task":data["Task"]})
    records.append({"Emp_No":emp_data.iloc[0]["Emp_No"], "Project_Details":emp_project_details , "Name":emp_data.iloc[0]["Name"]})

final_data = {"Records":records}

print(final_data)
```

If you have any question about the code above, feel free to ask. I'll also leave below the documentation i've used to solve your problem (you may wanna check that):

- unique : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html
- loc : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html
- iloc : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html